# change iframe width and height using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

how cai i change width and height on iframe is src link ? using javascript code below i am able to change width and height of iframe but when there is iframe like this

```
<iframe id="myFrame" src="http://domain.com/page.php?width=400&height=400" height="400" width="400"></iframe>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Change</button>
```

how do i change width and height here `page.php?width=400&height=400` ? is it possible using javascript ?

here's my javascript code to change width and height of iframe

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myFrame").height = "400";
    document.getElementById("myFrame").width = "400";
}
</script>
```

Comment: when do you call this function?

Comment: on click @MayankPatel

Comment: You have to take the src attribute and do some string manipulation and then put the src attribute again. But doing this will reload the iframe again.

Comment: please give my answer a try and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: @PankajKumarSingh yes but how to do it can yyou please answer the question ? thanks for your time

Comment: Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uttampankajsingh/pckgxxxs/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var url =document.getElementById("myFrame").getAttribute("src");
var newUrl = url.substring(0,url.indexOf("width")) + "width=500&height=500";
document.getElementById("myFrame").setAttribute("src",newUrl);
```

Comment: dear, how do i make this to work on size of iframe also ? my point is i want this code to work also on resizing iframe not just the src of it

Comment: You should be able to change the values with this:

document.getElementById("myFrame").setAttribute("width","500")
document.getElementById("myFrame").setAttribute("height","500")

Comment: so what you mean i make your code like this `<script>
      function myFunction() {
      var url =document.getElementById("myFrame").getAttribute("src");
      var newUrl = url.substring(0,url.indexOf("width")) + "width=200&height=100"
      document.getElementById("myFrame").setAttribute("src",newUrl)
      document.getElementById("myFrame").setAttribute("width","200‌​") document.getElementById("myFrame").setAttribute("height","10‌​0")
      }
      </script>` ?

Comment: no but it doesn't do anything at all this is how i put it exactly `<script> function myFunction() { var url =document.getElementById("myFrame").getAttribute("src"); var newUrl = url.substring(0,url.indexOf("width")) + "width=200&height=100" document.getElementById("myFrame").setAttribute("src",‌​newUrl) document.getElementById("myFrame").setAttribute("width‌​","200‌​") document.getElementById("myFrame").setAttribute("height","10‌​‌​0") } </script>`

Comment: remember to put a semicolon (;) after each sentence. It should be

<script> function myFunction() {
 var url =document.getElementById("myFrame").getAttribute("src"); 
 var newUrl = url.substring(0,url.indexOf("width")) + "width=200&height=100";
 document.getElementById("myFrame").setAttribute("src",‌​newU‌​rl);
 document.getElementById("myFrame").setAttribute("width‌​","2‌​00‌​");
 document.getElementById("myFrame").setAttribute("height","10‌​‌​‌​0");
 } 
 </script>

Comment: thanks dear tat worked perfectly. one thing i need from you if it's not to big for you to make in same code. i have stying on iframe like this `<iframe style="width:500;height:500;" ` using same code i am sure i can change width and height in style instead of current code will add width and height on iframe

Comment: Yes, just set attribute style to whatever you want, like this:

document.getElementById("myFrame").setAttribute("style​","width:1200;height:1200;");

Comment: bro check my question at this link if you can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42430239/heres-my-javascript-to-resize-iframe-and-need-some-edit

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    $("iframe").width(678);
    $("iframe").height(526);
}
```

or you want to do using id then like this :

```
function myFunction() {
    $("#myFrame").width(678);
    $("#myFrame").height(526);
}
```

If you have 2 iframe and you only want to apply to 1st then like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        $("iframe:eq(1)").width(678);
        $("iframe:eq(1)").height(526);
    }
</script>
```

**EDIT:**You can update uour src of iframe using `.attr`

```
function myFunction() {
        $("#myFrame").width(678);
        $("#myFrame").height(526);
        $("#myFrame").attr('src','http://domain.com/page.php?width=678&height=526');
    }
```

Comment: dear i am trying to change here `page.php?width=400&height=400` not the size o iframe

Comment: means when you pass querystring it should apply to iframe?

Comment: you see my js code above it changes the size of iframe only but not the size of iframe src "Link" . so what i want to do when button clicked it should change the size of iframe src this one `page.php?width=400&height=400` you see there is width and height on link

Comment: you see @PankajKumarSingh is comment, he said doing what he knows will reload iframe again. i don't have problem if it reloads iframe but the size of src link must change on click button

Comment: I am trying to do that

Comment: thanks a lot for all you did dear but didn't work. that Agustin Dortona is answer worked

Comment: yeah alright you get your work done is more important.

Comment: but i think if you give a try to my edit it should work.

Comment: i tried it. i am not saying didn't work just like this. or maybe i did something wrong it didn't work because i don't know in javascript much